# Calling circles function when I'm forced to include it in a build function for a stateless widget

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

I'm trying to plot a circle on button press. I'm forced to place it like so:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<void> _makeCircles() async {
      Set<Circle> circles = Set.from([
        Circle(
            circleId: CircleId("myCircle"),
            radius: 500,
            center: _createCenter(),
            fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.2),
            strokeColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 16, 0, 0.5))
      ]);
    }
    if (lat == null || lng == null) {
      return Scaffold();
    }
      return Scaffold(

          appBar: AppBar(title: Text(''), actions: <Widget>[
            PopupMenuButton<String>(
```

I tried placing it in initState but it wouldn't work.

The problem now is, my map can't find it:

```
      child: GoogleMap(
          markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
          initialCameraPosition:
          CameraPosition(target: LatLng(lat, lng), zoom: 6.0),
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          compassEnabled: true,
          mapToolbarEnabled: true,
          zoomControlsEnabled: true,
          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          circles: circles,
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            controller.setMapStyle(Utils.mapStyles);
          }),
```

"Undefined name 'circles'"

How can I call circles here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above your build method, place this line of code

```
Set<Circle> circles;
```

In your build method change

```
Set<Circle> circles = Set.from([
        Circle(
            circleId: CircleId("myCircle"),
            radius: 500,
            center: _createCenter(),
            fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.2),
            strokeColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 16, 0, 0.5))
      ]);
```

To this

```
circles = Set.from([
        Circle(
            circleId: CircleId("myCircle"),
            radius: 500,
            center: _createCenter(),
            fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.2),
            strokeColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 16, 0, 0.5))
      ]);
```

This would work.

For dynamic lat, long and radius

Step 1: get latitude, longitude and radius variable.

```
var latitude, longitude,radius;
```

```
TextFormField(
  decoration:InputDecoration(
    
    hintText: '"Enter latitude',
    
  ),
  onChanged: (String value) {
   latitude=value;
  },
),
TextFormField(
  decoration:InputDecoration(
    
    hintText: '"Enter radius",
    
  ),
  onChanged: (String value) {
   radius=value;
  },
),
TextFormField(
  decoration:InputDecoration(
    
    hintText: '"Enter latitude',
    
  ),
  onChanged: (String value) {
   latitude=value;
  },
),
```

Now, in circles

```
center: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
radius: radius,
```

Comment: Please accept this as the answer, and upvote, if it helped :)

Comment: hrmm. I put Set<Circle> circles = <Circle>{}; Both worked. Thank you!

Comment: I don't suppose you know how to pass strings from TextFormFields as center lat and long? :]

Comment: Sorry i didn't get it? You want to the user to enter lat and long?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Lat, long, and radius.

Comment: it almost works!!! thank you so much. I'm posting another question where I got stuck trying to convert it to double.

Comment: please post the question, and upvote if it helped :)

Comment: I posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321003/issue-with-initializing-how-can-i-convert-something-like-this-to-a-static-membe

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (lat == null || lng == null) {
      return Scaffold();
    }
    Set<Circle> circles = Set.from([
      Circle(
          circleId: CircleId("none"),
          center: _createCenter(),
          radius: 500,
          fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.2),
          strokeColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 16, 0, 0.5))
    ]);

    Future<void> _makeCircles() async {
      Set<Circle> circles = Set.from([
        Circle(
            circleId: CircleId("none"),
            radius: 500,
            center: _createCenter(),
            fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.2),
            strokeColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 16, 0, 0.5))
      ]);
    }

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(''), actions: <Widget>[
```

even better:

```
  Future<void> _makeCircles() async {

    setState(() {
    circles = Set.from([
      Circle(
          circleId: CircleId("none"),
          radius: 1500,
          center: _createCenter(),
          fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.2),
          strokeColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 16, 0, 0.5))]);
//    Navigator.pop(context);

//      circles = circles;
    });
  }
  
Set<Circle> circles = <Circle>{};
```