# Issue with initializing. How can I convert something like this to a static member? if that's what I need to do

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

I'm trying to pass data from text inputs (lat, long, radius) to plot a circle:

```dart
Map<double, double> n1 = (platitude)
    .map((key, value) => MapEntry(double.parse(key), double.parse(value)));
List longitudelist = platitude.values.toList();
    
    
Future<void> _makeCircles() async {
 setState(() {
   circles = Set.from([
     Circle(
         circleId: CircleId("none"),
         center: LatLng(platitude, plongitude),
         radius: radius,
         fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .5),
         strokeColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 16, 0, .4))
   ]);
 });
}
```

I'm unsuccessful in converting to double as required by center: LatLng because the values are not static. Anybody know a workaround?

Edit:

As requested, I've added more code to make this more reproducible:

This is how I'm grabbing my latitude, longitude, and radius as strings from user input:

```
TextFormField(
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          initialValue: "33.2038241",
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Enter latitude',
                          ),
                          onChanged: (String value) {
                            platitude = value;
                          },
                        ),
```

You can ignore the initial value, that was for testing only.
Now, I'm trying to pass that string into Geolocator's `center: LatLng(platitude, plongitude)`. as shown above.

This requires values as a double. I tried converting to a double like so:

```
  var platitude = double.parse(platitude);
```

This doesn't work. "Only Static Members can be accessed as initializers."

So, I did a bit of research and tried calling it in initstate like so:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocation();

    platitude = new TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      controller: filterController);
    plongitude = new TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      controller: filterController);
    radius = new TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      controller: filterController);

  }

  double n1 = double.parse(platitude); 
  
  TabController _tabController;
  final filterController = new TextEditingController(text: "Search");

  TextFormField platitude;
  TextFormField plongitude;
  TextFormField radius;
```

This resulted in "The argument TextFormField cant be assigned String" and "Only static members can be accessed..."

Anybody know how I can make this work? :/

Comment: What makes you think that you need  a `static` member?  Could you please provide a reproducible example of what you want?  It's hard to help you since there's a lot of code that you aren't showing, and you're assuming that people know what `LatLng` and `Circle` are.

Comment: The error I received indicated "only static members can be accessed as initializers." I need to pass a double into LatLng as Flutter's Geolocator expects it this way: center: LatLng(latitude, longitude).  my lat and long come from user input strings. i tried converting like so: var platitude = double.parse(platitude); and got the above error. I also tried calling in initState /w SingleTickerProviderStateMixin but it didn't work.. :/

Comment: @jamesdlin Added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling that you can't do:

```dart
  double n1 = double.parse(platitude);
```

in the *class definition* because `platitude` isn't `static`.  Inline initializers (that aren't `late`) for non-`static` members in the class definition are executed when the object is *constructed*.  It does not make sense to initialize non-`static` members from other non-`static` members because those other members *aren't initialized yet*.  More specifically in your example, `platitude` won't be initialized until *after* `initState` is called.

In general, if you want to initialize a non-`static` member from another non-`static` member, instead just nee to move the initialization *somewhere else*.  Since `n1` depends on `platitude`, it'd make sense to initialize `n1` right after you initialize `platitude` in `initState`.

That said, in your case, that also does not make sense.  You probably don't want to initialize it right after you create an *empty* `TextFormField`.  Furthermore, `double.parse` expects a `String` argument, not a `TextFormField`.

You probably want to do sometihng like:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    ...

    platitude = TextFormField(
      ...
      onSaved: (String value) => n1 = double.parse(value),
    );
```

(It's also odd to do that work in `initState`; usually you'd just construct widgets such as `TextFormField` in the `build` method instead.)

Answer (score -1):

Update:-
Do this instead,

```
var latitude, longitude;
Future<void> _makeCircles() async {
 setState(() {
   circles = Set.from([
     Circle(
         circleId: CircleId("none"),
         center: LatLng(double.parse(latitude), double.parse(longitude)),
         radius: radius,
         fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .5),
         strokeColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 16, 0, .4))
   ]);
 });
}
```

And, in your TextFormFields,

```
TextFormField(
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          initialValue: "33.2038241",
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Enter latitude',
                          ),
                          onChanged: (String value) {
                            latitude=value;
                          },
                        ),
```

Now, you can call the method _makeCircles() whenever needed, but make sure you always call that after getting the latitude and longitude initialised, as, if you will call the method before that, it'll throw a noSuchMethod error.

Comment: Do the same for plongitude.

Comment: Please upvote and accept this as  the answer, if it helped :)

Comment: You can't initialize a variable from itself.  Even assuming you mean `static var n1 = double.parse(platitude);`, that's still wrong since it's `platitude` that needs to be `static`.  Even assuming you mean `static TextFormField platitude`, it's answering the wrong part of an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): yes, that would avoid the error message, but it does not make sense for that member to be `static`.

Comment: Yup, i noticed my mistake ^_^', btw thanks for explaining.